# QR link use statistics

Tags: links, google-analytics, qr-code

I want to create a QR code for a given link to a website I don't own, but wish to promote. Mainly due to curiosity I want to track how many sites that link was visited from my code (and anything that can be provided by Google Analytics). Is there a website like tiny.cc or similar that would allow me to create links to other websites while still providing me with in-depth usage statistics, or would I have to create my own redirection website and embed Analytics code in it to get such information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This being a QR code doesn't make it any different to any other URL you might want to track.

Create a page on your own website that does a redirect to the other site, and and make a QR code to the URL on your website.

So people click the QR, go to your site, and end up at the target site.  Then you can measure the hits to the URL.   Use a meta-refresh redirect if you want to use google analytics.

Or create a short url at tiny.cc that the QR code points to and track it there.

Answer (score 1):

Both **[bit.ly](http://bit.ly)** and Google's **[goo.gl](http://goo.gl/)** have Qr codes and click statistics.

Comment: goo.gl is not accepting new users.